# Save each index into each button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a Tic Tac Toe game and want to display index in each of the button, like below. I'm using React right now.

```
<button id="button" index="0" nav-selectable="true" class="Square_Square__1MfjH"></button>
<button id="button" index="1" nav-selectable="true" class="Square_Square__1MfjH"></button>
...
<button id="button" index="8" nav-selectable="true" class="Square_Square__1MfjH"></button>
```

Here is my code:

```
const Square = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button 
                id="button"
                nav-selectable="true"
                key={props.index} // Display this in the button
                className={classes.Square} 
                onClick={() => { props.onClick(); }}
                >
                {props.value}
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
class Board extends Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
        return <Square 
            index={i} // Take the i from below (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
            value={this.props.squares[i]}        
            onClick={() => { this.props.onClick(i); }}
            />;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={classes.Board}>
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className={classes.Board}>
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className={classes.Board}>
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

However, this method seems not working. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Index should be unique, so you should not use id="button" but something like id="button-index" where index is your number

Comment: Are you just trying to display the index ***on*** the button, like where the text would be located? It isn't exactly clear what you're trying to do. Also, element `id` attributes *should* be globally unique.

Comment: Do you want to display the `index` in the content or just as a prop of a button?

Comment: I just want to display on the button like this
<button index="0"></button> in the browser, so I can select it from other js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it as an attribute, you can use `index` or `data-index`.

Change your square example to:

```
<button 
  id="button"
  nav-selectable="true"
  key={props.index} // Display this in the button
  index={props.index}
  className={classes.Square} 
  onClick={() => { props.onClick(); }}
>
  {props.value}
</button>
```